Add a countdown timer to the console input
I'm trying to add timer to a console application. The idea is - the app reads user input from the console (if there's any), waits 10 seconds and then shows next question. If there's no input - it terminates the countdown and shows the next question (new countdown starts). Now there's now countdown (timer is implemented in the background with Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith).
It is how the programm now looks like:
const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CancelIoEx(IntPtr handle, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var read = false;
        Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            if (!read)
            {
                var handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
                CancelIoEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        });

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Question Number (10 seconds remaining):");
            var key = Console.ReadLine();
            read = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Key read");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation canceled");
        }
    }
}

I tried the following async method (which receives a token from the main thread if there's no input und countdown is over or if a user managed to give an answer faster than in 10 secs). But I have problems with its implementation. I also tried - "await Task.WhenAny(userInputTask, countdownTask).ContinueWith(_ =>", but in this case, Console.ReadLine() doesn't stop after the countdown is over (it still wants an input from user when the next question is shown).
static async Task DisplayCountdownAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.Write("\r{0} seconds left, your guess - ", i);
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Asynchronously delay for 1 second
    }


This similar question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714691/wait-set-time-for-user-input-c-sharp-console-app

As the link from Bart McEndree suggests, move away from Console.ReadLine() and instead use Console.KeyAvailable and Console.ReadKey() from within a loop.
